# Options Binding overrides initial View Model value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I tried to follow the other similar questions on Stack Overflow but thus far have been unsuccessful in fixing the problem.

I am using jQuery AJAX to retrieve several items: a contact and its associated information, all available salutation types, all available email types and all available phone types.

I have successfully bound the options to the select boxes.  However, it appears to overwrite the 'value' binding that holds the initial view model value.

Could any of you help me solve this?  Please let me know if you have any questions for clarification.

Please see the code below:

View Model:

```
function contactPageViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.contact = ko.observable();
    self.availableSalutations = ko.observableArray();
    self.availableEmailTypes = ko.observableArray();
    self.availablePhoneTypes = ko.observableArray();
    self.availableAddressTypes = ko.observableArray();
}
```

where contact is an object coming from the server, which includes the element `contact.salutation`.

The json coming back for contact is:

```
{
    //...
    "createdBy":null,
    "createdOn":1392848929000,
    "updatedBy":null,
    "updatedOn":1392848929000,
    "contactId":305,
    "salutation":{"salutationId":102,"salutation":"Mrs."},
    "firstName":"Laura",
    "middleInitial":"K",
    "lastName":"Ritchey" 
    //...
}
```

the json coming back from `availableSalutations` (which is a property of a json object wrapper 'listObject') is:

```
[{"salutationId":41,"salutation":"Ms."},
{"salutationId":101,"salutation":"Mr."},
{"salutationId":66,"salutation":"CDR"},
{"salutationId":81,"salutation":"LCDR"},
{"salutationId":102,"salutation":"Mrs."},
{"salutationId":121,"salutation":"Mr."},
{"salutationId":64,"salutation":"LTC"}]
```

The code to map the JSON result to the knockout observables:

```
contactPageViewModel.contact = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.listObject[0]);
        contactPageViewModel.availableEmailTypes = ko.mapping
                .fromJS(data.listObject[1]);
        contactPageViewModel.availableSalutations = ko.mapping
                .fromJS(data.listObject[2]);
....
        applyBindings();
```

The HTML:

```html
<label for="rank"> Rank / Title: </label> 
<select data-bind="optionsText: 'salutation', 
                   options: availableSalutations, 
                   value: contactPageViewModel.contact.salutation"
        class="rankList" 
        name="Rank" 
        id="rankSelect">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `value: $root.contact().salutation` instead of `value: contactPageViewModel.contact.salutation`.

Or:

```html
<label for="rank"> Rank / Title: </label>
<!-- ko with: contact -->
<select data-bind="options: $root.availableSalutations, optionsText: 'salutation', value: salutation" class="rankList" name="Rank" id="rankSelect">
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Update:**
You could look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/pbfLh/). May be it contains a lot of excess code and you can simplify it, but the main things is to separate initial and selected salutations and add `optionsCaption` to select bindings:

```
var initialSalutation = new salutationViewModel(data.salutation);
```

And:

```
self.salutation = ko.observable();
self.displayedSalutation = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.salutation()) {
        return self.salutation();
    } else {
        return initialSalutation;
    }
})
```

**Update 2:**
Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/pbfLh/3/). I've added `optionsValue: 'salutationId'` to select bindings and move `displayedSalutation` to `contactPageViewModel`.
I think problem was with matching objects (select item and salutation from contact). When value of select is `salutationId` and contact salutation also `salutationId` (number value, not object) all working good.

Comment: I tried both of those, and they both had the same result of showing the first 'availableSalutation' instead of the contact salutation

Comment: I do like the syntax of the $root.* though; looks cleaner

Comment: One more note - when I used the first one, I had to take out the () because it said it was not a function.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: when I look at the fiddle, it shows the --select salutation-- in the select field.  Do you know how to make it show Mrs. upon load?

Comment: @LauraRitchey Look at Update 2.

Comment: thanks!  Trying it now, will let you know how it goes in a few

Comment: thanks so much!  It works great :) I just passed in the contact and salutations into the view model after retrieving them from the server and it works!  appreciate all your help.